# Proper way to set parent of a tree node in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a custom tree. Each node (BindingNode is how I call them) contains a BindingNodeCollection that implements [ICollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92t2ye13.aspx) and contains more nodes. My problem is that, the user should be able to access each node's parent with a readonly property called Parent, just like in a [TreeNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.aspx). But the nodes are added to a BindingNodeCollection by calling BindingNodeCollection's `Add(BindingNode node)` method. BindingNodeCollection knows what it's own parent is, but, can't assign BindingNode's Parent in the  `Add(BindingNode node)` method because Parent should be readonly. The functionality I'm trying to achieve is basically the same as the functionality of a [TreeNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.aspx) and a [TreeNodeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.aspx) in a [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aspx):

-TreeNode's Parent is readonly.

-TreeNodes are assigned to a TreeNodeCollection by calling TreeNodeCollection's `Add(TreeNode node)` method.

-TreeNode's Parent gives the TreeNode that contains the TreeNodeCollection where the TreeNode was added.

-TreeNodeCollection is NOT defined inside TreeNode in order to have access to the Parent private field.

This is when I miss C++'s `friend`. :(

Comment: I decided to use Marc's method: add an internal SetParent to BindingNode. Is the less nasty thing to do I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several methods that you can achieve what you're after, it really depends on how much security you envision needing.  Is this a library or a 'closed' application that only you or your colleagues will touch? Here are some suggestions and questions to consider before going with them.

1. Make the property setter on BindingNode be internal set; 
   *Do you trust everyone that is in this assembly to not orphan children?*
2. Expose the BindingNodeCollection as ReadOnly and provide methods to modify the collection 
   on the BindingNode itself.  The Add can set the private Parent property. Remove will be required to set the Parent property back to null.  *This is pretty locked down, is polluting your base node class worth the peace of mind?*
3. Accept that transparency is more important than security for you, and expose the Parent setter as public. *Do you trust **everyone** that can see your classes not to orphan children?*

For further reading and maybe better ideas, what you're almost describing is the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).  There is a **TON** of discussion on security versus transparency for this pattern and most of it relates to exposing these classes for the public to consume in some API.  It may be overkill for your situation, or it may be exactly what you need to consider, I have no idea given your question what the scope is.

Answer (score 2):

The internal modifier is C#'s equivalent to the friend class, to make the Parent's SET method accessible only to classes within the same assembly.

```
TreeNode Parent { get; internal set;}
```

Comment: I never really understood the internal modifier. "Same assembly" means same whole program?

Comment: @jsoldi: no, same binary. same C# project. Whether that project is an executable or dll.

Comment: Assembly means specific EXE or DLL that the code is compiled into.  You could have an application that uses an EXE and multiple DLL's for example, but only the code within the same DLL as the TreeNode would be able to call anything marked internal

Comment: Anyway, there MUST be a complete solution since .NET's TreeView do it.

Comment: For all we know, .Net TreeView could be using internal to do exactly that.  you cant set the Parent because you cannot create a type within the same assembly.

Comment: TreeNode has an internal `SetParent` method.

Comment: Ohhh! Then that was it. Well my solution is quite radical. I'll get rid of my whole class and derive my nodes from TreeNode. I just didn't want to hold my internal data in a control to keep user-interface from internal-data separated, but actually TreeNode can exist by itself without a TreeView.

Comment: Ya, Ive actually got server side code (no interface) that use TreeNodes to store/work with hierarchical data.

Comment: Wait. I just screwed. Now I remember why I didn't use TreeNode before: can't be XML serialized. :(

Comment: I actually wrote my own TreeView-->XML method and XML-->TreeNode constructor, not that hard if you dont have a lot of Data in the node.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class BindingNode
{
    private BindingNode _parent;
    private List<BindingNode> _children = new List<BindingNode>();

    public IEnumerable<BindingNode> Children
    {
        get { return _children; }
    }

    public BindingNode Parent
    {
        get { return _parent; }
    }

    public void AddChild( BindingNode node )
    {
        node._parent = this;
        _children.Add( node );
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, that's another possibility. But I also need to be able to access the children with an indexer and stuff like that. I think I'm going to use a BindingNodeCollection and add a internal SetParent method to it. At least we know that's what .NET's TreeNode do, so shouldn't be a horrible idea.

Comment: Instead of IEnumerable<BindingNode> you could use ReadOnlyCollection<BindingNode>.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's called the decorator pattern? C'mon points if I'm right for that. I can never remember the names of patterns..

I'd make a class that is constructed in the add and at construction has the Parent property set, and just owns the node as a member. If there's an interface for BindingNode then i'd implement the interface with all the methods and properties pass throughs to the actual BindingNode.

```
public class BoundNode : INode
{
    private INode _thisNode { get; private set; }
    public INode Parent { get; private set; }
    public BoundNode(INode bindingNode, INode parent)
    {
        _thisNode = bindingNode;
        Parent = parent;
    }

    // Implement pass throughs to the _thisNode member

}
```

Then the add method would implement

```
public Add(INode someNode)
{
    _nodeList.Add(new BoundNode(someNode, this.Parent));
}
```

Or something like that.. however your collection knows about it's node context..

Comment: this does however assume you know the Parent when you create the node.

Comment: Problem is, you wouldnt be able to create a node until you were ready to add it to it's parent.  Might not know the parent at first... or how about a root node?

Comment: @Niel N: I'm assuming the Node is already constructed, for root node you would create a normal BindingNode, and add other BindingNodes to it's collection, except when you retrieved a node from the BindingNodeCollection you would just receive this decorator on the originally added instance. With the pass throughs though it would behave as the original instance. Ideally INode would implement parent, bindingnode would throw not implemented exception or return itself, and boundnode would properly have implementation for the parent concept.

Comment: @Jimmy. In your Add example, wouldn't you place `this` as the second arg, not `this.Parent`?

Comment: @Mark H: in Add this is a BindingNodeCollection not a BindingNode (I'm guessing, and at a guess the BindingNodeCollection maybe knows the node that owns it by a property named Parent?)

Comment: What's to stop them from just adding directly to the BindingNodeCollection?  How do I Remove a node if the parent can't be set after construction?

Comment: @Marc: From the poster: the nodes are added to a BindingNodeCollection by calling BindingNodeCollection's Add(BindingNode node)

Comment: @Jimmy Hoffa, I am missing your point. TreeNodeCollection also has remove methods that _effectively_ set parent to null for the BoundNode.  That's not possible for yours.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is to assign the child node to the parent.
Like this:

```
parentTreeNode.Nodes.Add(childTreeNode);
```