# Why do I get a "System.StackOverflowException was unhandled " exception when serializing?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to serialize the following class:

```
[Serializable()]
public class BindingNode : IEnumerable<BindingNode>
{
    public BindingNode()
    {
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerator<BindingNode> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Add(BindingNode item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This was originally an ICollection instead of an IEnumerable, but I removed as much as I could of my code to keep only what caused the error. Here's the code where the exception occurs:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingNode node = new BindingNode();
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Stream stream = File.Open(saveFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Create);
            XmlSerializer xmlFormatter = new XmlSerializer(node.GetType());
            xmlFormatter.Serialize(stream, node);
            stream.Close();
        }            
    }
```

Comment: As a side note, you don't need to mark your class Serializable for the XmlSerializer.

Comment: Also, you should be using the "using" block to clean up the stream, not just a .Close. As you have seen, the serialize code can throw which could leave an open handle to the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour for XMLSerializer is hitting a loop because as part of trying to work out how to serialse a `BindingNode`, it then tries to figure out how to serialise an `IEnumerable<BindingNode>`, and to do that it tries to figure out how to serialise a `BindingNode`.

There's nothing to say that you can't have `BindingNode` implement `IEnumerable<BindingNode>`, just that the default XMLSerializer behaviour isn't going to work.

If you implement IXmlSerializable, then you control the serialisation yourself. Since you already know the structure of a BindingNode, you don't have to work that out at runtime! If you've a guarantee of an acyclic graph (it's impossible to have a BindingNode that is an ancestor of itself), then this is trivial:

```
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("BindingNode");
    //More stuff here.
    foreach(BindingNode contained in this)
        contained.WriteXml(writer);
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

If the graph can by cyclic, it's just slightly more complicated in that you need to be able to instead of writing an element with all the details included, that you write an element that references a node already serialised to the stream, as otherwise the actual writing goes on forever and if you're lucky you hit a different cause of a stack overflow pretty soon (if you're unlucky the program merrily writes gigs and gigs of a file to disk first, and then hits it).

```
public int SomeSortOfUniqueID
{
    get
    {
        //guess what this property has to do!
    }
}
public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
{
    WriteXml(writer, new HashSet<BindingNode>());
}
private void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer, HashSet<BindingNode> alreadyWritten)
{
    if(alreadyWritten.Add(this))
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("BindingNode");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("uniqueID", SomeSortOfUniqueID.ToString());
        //More stuff here.
        foreach(BindingNode contained in this)
            contained.WriteXml(writer, alreadyWritten);
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
    else
    {
        //we need to reference a node already mentioned in the document.
        writer.WriteStartElement("BindingNode");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("refID", SomeSortOfUniqueID.ToString());
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

Of course, you'll also have to implement ReadXml() to parse the XML back again.

Comment: Oh, even if the graph is acyclic, the second option may be better if nodes can have more than one parent, as there's still the chance of the same node being serialised twice. While it won't cause a loop, it will cause waste, and it will deserialise as two different objects which as well as being further waste, looses the property of identity.

Answer (score 2):

This would be your problem: `BindingNode : IEnumerable<BindingNode>` This would be recursive and you would encouter a `StackOverFlowException`. Typically people create two classes.

The single class:

```
public class BindingNode
{
   /*..*/
}
```

The colleciton class:

```
public class BindingNodeCollection : IEnumerable<BindingNode>
{
   /*..*/
}
```

This approach usually also increases cohesion and satisfies the Single Responsiblity Principle (SRP). It does this by seperating concerts. Collection logic is placed in the collection class and then the original class does what it was entended to do.

Comment: So I guess there is no solution other than implementing the non generic version of IEnumerable?

Comment: The only other solution that comes to mind would be to create two classes. One for `BindingNode` and one that is the `BindingNodeCollection`. The latter could inherit from `IEnumerable<BindingNode>`.

Comment: Well I was doing that until I found that causes another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3452376/proper-way-to-set-parent-of-a-tree-node-in-c

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to accomplish now. I have posted an answer on your other question.