# C# How do you solve a circular object reference

Tags: c#, serialization, object

I've run into what i belive could be a major issue for my code design and i was hoping someone here could explain to me how i would work around the issue.

I have 2 classes which each have a property of the other class creating a circular reference. I plan on serializing these classes and using XSLT to format the output but i'm assuming this will fail due to the circular reference.

Example

```
public class Book
{
  public BookShop TheShop = new BookShop();
}
public class BookShop
{
  list<Book> Books = new list<Book>();
}
```

So from this example each book will be in a bookShop and each bookshop will have many books. If i serialize the bookshop it will then serialize each book which then serialize a bookshop and so on round and round.  How should i handle this?

Answer (score 6):

Tag `TheShop` with an attribute to prevent its serialization.

[`[XmlIgnore]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute.aspx) with the default serializer.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/GameCatalog.aspx

Probably just a problem with your example, not your real code: Don't use public fields but properties. I think `XmlSerializer` doesn't even serialize public fields.

Comment: Sorry a quickly created example the real code is far more detailed.

Answer (score 1):

Add `[XmlIgnore]` to the `TheShop` property to prevent it from being serialized.

You can then set it manually when deserializing.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice would be to have the BookShop class implement an interface (IBookShop) and then have the Book class store the interface not the concrete class.  You should also make BookShop into a property in the Book class:

```
public class Book
{
    public Book(IBookShop bookShop)
    {
        TheStop = bookShop;
    }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public IBookShop TheShop { get; set; }
}
public interface IBookShop 
{
    void SomeMethod();
}
public class BookShop : IBookShop
{
    list<Book> Books = new list<Book>();
    public void SomeMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer`, you should decorate `TheShop` with `System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute`:

```
public class Book
{
  [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnore]
  public BookShop TheShop;
}
```

That is, assuming the `BookShop` is the root object you wish to serialize.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)

Comment: Does that basically tell the serializer to skip that property. Which is kind of ok but if i at a different time serialize a book i cant see which shop its from. Also forgetting the XML for a second can i even have circular reference between my objects? sounds like a really bad idea to me.

Comment: Yes, it causes the serializer to skip that property (or field).  Circular references in objects are fine and good (like between adjacent items in a doubly-linked list) because they allow you to traverse the relationship in both directions.  The problem is that XML doesn't have pointers or references in the way that objects in memory do; serialization forces a hierarchy.  If you only need to know *which* shop the book is in, you could make some identifying property of it serializable on the book: public class Book { public string ShopName { get { return TheShop.Name; } } }

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check whether this is really a problem. If you always care about a bookshop when you have a book, and you always care about all the books a bookshop has, then it's perfectly sensible to have the whole graph serialised. This doesn't result in an infinite loop, because the serialisation uses an identifier to indicate a reference to an object already serialised (there is a bug if you do an XML serialisation of a graph with a circular reference in its **types**, but that's a bug rather than inherent to the problem of serialising XML, as the fact that it can be resolved proves, see [Why do I get a "System.StackOverflowException was unhandled " exception when serializing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453476/) on that).

So, maybe you don't want to do anything here at all, and you're fine as you are.

Otherwise, the question is - just what do you want to serialise? Most suggestions so far have been to not serialise the `TheShop` property. This could be fine, or it may be useless if you will need to later access that shop.

If you have some sort of identifier (id number, uri) for each shop, then you could perhaps memoise - access to `TheShop` looks first at whether a private `_theShop` is null, and if it is, loads the relevant object into `_theShop` based on that identifier. Then you just need to serialise the identifier, not the full object.

Finally, if you are using XSLT to format the output to some other specification (whether XHTML for display, or something else) you may find it simpler just to roll your own XML serialisation. While this is a more complicated task in many ways, the fact that the XML produced by serialisation isn't particularly convenient for reformatting for display may mean that overall it's simpler this way. Indeed, if this is your only reason for serialising (you will never deserialise from the XML produced) then it may be much easier, as you need only consider what the XML for display needs, and not worry about anything else. Hence serialising may not be the best approach at all, but simply a `ToXml()` method, or a `WriteBookToXml()` method in another class.