# An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in VimService55.XmlSerializers.dll

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, powershell, stack-overflow

I am working on an asp.net mvc-5 web application and i am using ap.net version 4.5.

Inside my web application I am executing some power-shell scripts to get some hardware info about some servers and VMs, and get back the results inside my code, as follows:

```
var shell = PowerShell.Create();
string PsCmd =       
    "add-pssnapin VMware.VimAutomation.Core; $vCenterServer = '" 
    + vCenterName.Trim() + "';$vCenterAdmin = '" + vCenterUsername.Trim() 
    + "' ;$vCenterPassword = '" + vCenterPassword + "';" 
    + System.Environment.NewLine;

PsCmd += "$VIServer = Connect-VIServer -Server $vCenterServer -User $vCenterAdmin -Password $vCenterPassword;" + System.Environment.NewLine;
PsCmd += "Get-VMHost " + System.Environment.NewLine;

shell.Commands.AddScript(PsCmd);

dynamic results = shell.Invoke(); 

var temp_result = results[0].BaseObject == null ? results[0] : results[0].BaseObject;
var otherIdentityInfo = temp_result.ExtensionData.Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo;
```

now currently when i run this inside my Visual Studio 2012 professional , i will get the following exception :-

```
System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in VimService55.XmlSerializers.dll
```

on

```
var otherIdentityInfo = temp_result.ExtensionData.Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo;
```

So can anyone adivce on this? I know that in general a "StackOverflowException" exception is related to the fact that too many data exists inside the stack, but in my case I do not have control over this data as I am scanning VM server information. So can anyone advice on this please?

**EDIT**

I am not sure what is really raising the error (the debugger OR the code)? because when i try calling this code on the hosted application inside IIS (not inside Visual Studio) I will get null value for the `otherIdentityInfo` variable, rather than getting an exception. However, when i debug the code inside Visual Studio using Autos i will get the exception, so as @JmaesP mentioned the exception is being raised by the debugger, but not sure how i can debug this value to see why i am getting null??

Comment: Have you debugged code to see if `temp_result` is null? I think it may be recursively calling function, circular reference that is most likely causing the `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: @JamesP I am using "_Autos_" debugging inside visual studio. now the problem if that currently i am getting null values inside my application for the  "otherIdentityInfo",, so i am trying to debug the "_emp_result.ExtensionData.Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo_" using "_Autos_" to see what is the data i am getting.. now your point is valid is that the autos debugging is raising the exception, because when  execute the code on the hosted application i will get null value for the "_emp_result.ExtensionData.Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo_" and not an exception ...

Comment: so mainly i will get the exception when debugging the code inside Visual Studio,,, but at the same time i need to debig the code to check why i am getting null value on the follow line inside my hosted application "_emp_result.ExtensionData.Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo_" ?

Comment: Does VS show you the stacktrace?

Comment: @DirkVollmar No not every thing .. now for the data i am looking for i will be getting red circle with this messages "_Function evaluation was abroted_"  OR "_cannot evaluate the expression because debugging information has been optimized anyway_"

Comment: @DirkVollmar although i have disable code optimization for my project (project name>> right click >> properties >> Build>> un-check the code optimization),, so visual studio should not be doing any code optimizations and should read the full stack.. so not sure what is going on ?

Comment: Make sure that both the VimServices55.dll and the  VimService55.XmlSerializers.dll came from the exact same build – in particular debug vs release.    Also make sure anything else using the VimService55.dll in your stack was using the same reference and build target.   Also make sure that both the VimService55.dll and its XmlSerializer companion are being deployed and copied to your execution point.

Comment: Please may I request that you copy and paste the method declaration code in full?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A stack overflow exception from an XML serializer might indicate an issue with one of you serializable types. If the type declaration by itself is somewhat recursice, the default XML serializer will end up in inifite recursion. Consider this example:

```
[Serializable()]
public class Foo : IEnumerable<Foo>
{
    public Foo()
    {
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerator<Foo> GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Add(Foo item)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The default XML serializer first tries to figure out how to (de-)serialize an instance of `Foo`, then it tries to figure out how to (de-)serialize an `IEnumerable<Foo>`, and to do that it tries to figure out how to (de-)serialize a `Foo` — resulting in infinite recursion. Typically, a solution to this would to use a custom serializer as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3454347/40347).

However, in your case the serializer is provided by the third-party component. The exception likely occurs during the serialization/deserialization that is happening when objects are passed from the PowerShell session to your process. So what you could to is to change the object that is returned from the PowerShell script. Instead of returning a [`VMHost`](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/PowerCLI/PowerCLI41U1/html/VMHost.html) object (requiring to serialize the entire object tree of the `VMHost` object), you could just return the `SystemInfo` or `OtherIdentifyingInfo`.

Comment: so not sure how will custom XML  serializer will help in my case?

Comment: Ok i got your point , so i need to minimize the stack from the source ,, by tuning my power-shell script and force it to return only the required data "_OtherIdentifyingInfo_" in my case,, although this mean that i need to run the same power-shell multiple times to get the info i need..as i am also managing other info from the powershell script not only the "_OtherIdentifyingInfo_"

Comment: @johnG: It's rather not serializing the object at all that is causing problems than minimizing the stack.

Comment: so is it possible not to serialize the object at all in my case ?? and if i do so will i be able to get the data i want ??

Comment: @Drik Vollmar i just return back to this problem and i followed your approach `Instead of returning a VMHost object (requiring to serialize the entire object tree of the VMHost object), you could just return the SystemInfo or OtherIdentifyingInfo` and it worked well. where i run the folloiwng script `Get-VMHost | Select @{N=“Type“;E={$_.Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo | ?{$_.IdentifierType.Key -like "ServiceTag"}).IdentifierValue[1]}}`

Answer (score 2):

Large recursions can cause out-of-stack errors. 
Your problem is likely that your program is attempting to consume an infinite amount /very large amount of stack.

Without seeing your stack trace, it's a bit difficult to provide a definitive answer, but I think sticking to the basics leads me to believe the source of your StackOverflow is the **PsCmd +=** which continuously adding the data into the stack and results in StackOverflowException.

You can increase the stack size by using the below code:

> Editbin.exe /Stack:14000000 "$(TargetDir)MyProject.exe"

Have you analyzed your code to find out that how deep your recursion goes on average? Does it always hit a StackOverflow? Try hardcoding a single entity and see the result.

Since 64 bit code can up more stack space than equivalent 32 bit code, large recursions can cause out-of-stack errors to occur earlier.

In that case, making the stack larger is not a good idea either. Instead we should find the deeply recursive algorithm and make it into an iterative one.

For Stack-Trace;
You can read up this property: **Environment.StackTrace**.

If the stacktrace exceded a specific threshold that you preset, you can return the function.

***Note:*** From .Net 2.0 and above, you cannot get a StackOverflowException object using a try-catch block.

Let me know if at all it helps you.